# PhpStorm EAP installation error

Tags: phpstorm

I am trying to install PhpStorm EAP. When I open PhpStorm, the PhpStorm License Activation box appears. The EAP version is meant to be free. What am I doing wrong?

I'm installing `PhpStorm-EAP-143.1480.tar.gz` on Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS

Comment: I believe that is the license activation to activate the trial. EAP can only be used for 30 days without a license, as does the production version

Comment: did you just try and hit close?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

30 days EAP license is available for **major versions only** (e.g. v10.0.0).

Once major version is released, all subsequent EAP builds for minor releases (like the latest right now: v10.0.3) require proper license.

*It's not a bug or recent change -- it has always being like that (since very first PhpStorm version).*